# How do you calculate the mean value and autocorrelation function of a time series of data points?

Tags: statistics, definition

From Haykin's Adaptive filter theory:

> A stochastic process is an infinite number of realizations of a
>   process:
>
> A time series is defined as a particular realization of a stochastic
>   process

He also has this:

> Consider a discrete-time stochastic process represented by the time
>   series $u(n), u(n - 1), . . . , u(n - M)$, which may be complex
>   valued. To simplify the terminology, we use $u(n)$ to denote such a
>   process.  We define the mean-value function of the processs $\mu(n) =
>  E[u(n)]$ where $E$ denotes the statistical expectation operator.
>
> We define the autocorrelation function of the process $r(n, n - k) =
>  E[u(n)u(n - k)], k = 0, {1, {2, . . . }}$

If you have some time series of say $1000$ data points $u(n), \dots, u(n-1000)$, how do you take the expected value and autocorrelation function of this time series?  $E(X) = \sum_{x \in X} x P_X(x)$ is the expected value of a random variable, but since each point is a single value how can I find either of these functions?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your mean depends on the sample, i.e. this is not a stationary process, so 
$$\mu(k) = u(n-k) \qquad k = 0 \ldots 1000$$
The same applies to the autocorrelation function
$$r(i,j)=E(u(i)u(j)] \qquad 0 \leq i \leq 1000 ;\ 0 \leq j \leq 1000$$
So your question should be how do we estimate $\mu(k)$ and $r(i,j)$. On way of doing so is to estimate $\mu(k)$ as a sample mean
$$\hat{\mu}(k) = u(n - k) \qquad k = 0 \ldots 1000$$
and
$$\hat{r}(i,j)=u(i)u(j) \qquad 0 \leq i \leq 1000 ;\ 0 \leq j \leq 1000$$

**PS: Everything is completely different when you have a stationary process.**

Comment: So by $\mu(n) = E[u(n)] = u(n)$ you mean the expected value of a time series is just the time series?  As in if $[u(n), \dots, u(n-4)] = [1, 2,3,4,5]$, then $[E[u(1)], \dots, E[u(n-4)]] = [1,2,3,4,5]$?

Comment: No .. I do not mean that .. I mean an estimate of the means would be the time series, i.e. $$\hat{\mu}(0) = 1, \hat{\mu}(1) = 2 \ldots$$ as such

Comment: What do you explicitly mean by $\mu(k) = u(n-k)$?  To me this says "The expected value of $u(n-k)$ is $u(n-k)$"